# Ricci tensor in complex space forms

Tags: differential-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let 
\begin{align}
f:M^{2n}\to CQ_{c}^{N}
\end{align}
be an isometric immersion of　a Kähler manifold into a complex space form.
We consider an orthonormal basis $Y=X_{1},..,X_{2n}$ and then calculate Ricci tensor,
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Ric}(Y)=\sum_{j=1}^{2n}<R'(X_{j},Y)Y,X_{j}>=\frac{c}{4}[2n-1+3|SY|^{2}].
\end{align}
My question is how can I understand map $S$, the explanation in the paper by Dajczer and Rodriguez, On isometric immersions into complex space forms, is that $S:T_{x}M\to T_{x}M$ is given by $S=\pi\circ J'$, where $\pi : T_{x}CQ_{c}^{N}\to T_{x}M$ is the orthogonal projection. Is $S$ the tangent part of complex structure $J'$ on $CQ_{c}^{N}$?